# Call function exported as default within itself

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

When using the ES6 module system, I have the following default function:

```
export default function() {
  console.log('abc');
  callThisFunctionAgain();
}
```

How can I call this default function again from itself when it does not have a name to reference?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to give it a name? You can still export named functions as default.

Comment: `export default function callThisFunctionAgain() { ... }`

Comment: If you want a named function expression instead of function declaration you could wrap the function in parenthesis (if that's why you don't name it).

Comment: @MinusFour can you show an example please?